# SQL query for MAX/MIN of a sorted comma separated string based on an input range

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a column in oracle table which contains comma separated values of date in sorted order as below.

```
ID|LIST_OF_DATES
--|---------------
1 |2020-11-01,2020-11-04,2020-11-05,2020-11-10,2020-11-12,2020-11-14,2020-11-16,.....2020-11-26,2020-11-30
```

Here list of dates is not a continuous list of dates. My requirement is to get the index of the max value of list of dates falling within an input window. Example output for data provided above.

```
INPUT_DATE_FROM: 2020-11-10
INPUT_DATE_TO: 2020-11-15
```

For above input range.. we have three dates that fall within that range which are 2020-11-10,2020-11-12,2020-11-14 of which 2020-11-14 is max value. 2020-11-14 is the 6th value in the list of dates which is the output of query I need.

```
OUTPUT:
ID|INDEX_OF_MAX_DATE
1 |5 (Assuming 0 is the start index)
```

When that input window changes to say 2020-11-25 till 2020-11-30, then we have only two dates of which 2020-11-30 is the max value. I need index of this max value.

what is the best possible way to get this result using oracle SQL? My table will have roughly 4 -5 million unique IDs for which this computation should done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the list and then choose the max.  Here is one method:

```
with dates as (
      select regexp_substr(t.list_of_dates, '[^,]+', 1, level) as dte
      from  t
      connect by regexp_substr(t.list_of_dates, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
     )
select id, max(date)
from dates
where dte >= :start_date_str and date <= :end_date_str
group by id;
```

That said, you should fix your data model.  Storing multiple values in a string is bad.  Storing dates as strings is bad.

The above assumes that the parameters are strings, just like the values in the strings.  If they are dates, then you need to convert the strings to dates.

Comment: date casting is missing and preserved word is used as the derived column name currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string using simple string functions and then use analytic functions to find the index of the maximum value in the list:

```sql
WITH bounds ( id, list_of_dates, idx, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         list_of_dates,
         0,
         1,
         INSTR( list_of_dates, ',', 1 )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         list_of_dates,
         idx + 1,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR( list_of_dates, ',', end_pos + 1 )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
),
dates ( id, idx, value ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         idx,
         TO_DATE( 
           CASE end_pos
           WHEN 0
           THEN SUBSTR( list_of_dates, start_pos )
           ELSE SUBSTR( list_of_dates, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
           END,
           'YYYY-MM-DD'
         )
  FROM   bounds
)
SELECT id,
       idx,
       value
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         idx,
         value,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   dates
  WHERE  value BETWEEN DATE '2020-11-10' AND DATE '2020-11-15'
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, LIST_OF_DATES ) AS
SELECT 1, '2020-11-01,2020-11-04,2020-11-05,2020-11-10,2020-11-12,2020-11-14,2020-11-16,2020-11-26,2020-11-30' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | IDX | VALUE              
> -: | --: | :------------------
>  1 |   5 | 2020-11-14 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2bfa26c57042b8592ecfd53128a721ab)*

---

Or by using:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       d.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT *
         FROM   (
           SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS idx,
                  TO_DATE(
                    REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.list_of_dates, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL ),
                    'YYYY-MM-DD'
                  ) AS value
           FROM   DUAL
           CONNECT BY
                  LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.list_of_dates, '[^,]+' )
         )
         WHERE  value BETWEEN DATE '2020-11-10' AND DATE '2020-11-15'
         ORDER BY
                value DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
       ) d
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=901e4f2cf394a13da652fec6efc9c192)*